# Is Deolalikar's 2010 proof that $P \ne NP$ correct?

Tags: np-hardness, cc.complexity-theory

There was recently a claimed [proof that $P \ne NP$](http://science.slashdot.org/story/10/08/08/226227/Claimed-Proof-That-P--NP). Not long after its publication there were raised [some issues](http://slashdot.org/story/10/08/11/0239209/Possible-Issues-With-the-P--NP-Proof) with this proof.

So ... is the proof correct or not ? (Please only answer this if you have evidence ... this question might take some time until it's answered)

Comment: why the vote to close ?

Comment: I think the question should specify which proof it refers to (at least mention name of the author). It is clear now, but may not be clear in a year from now.

Comment: IMO you should address certain potential flaws in the proof. Voted to close because of the lack of specificity of the question (the quality of the posts).

Comment: The link does refer to the recent story, although I'd much rather the OP link to the polymath wiki or Deolalikar's page than a slashdot post that seems less permanent

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In one word: No.

It seems that there are some fatal flaws in Deolalikar's proposed proof. The real question now is if the "proof" has any useful ideas that can be built upon. In any case, it seems that the proof in its current form simply isn't correct, and can't be corrected either. On the other hand, Deolalikar has not given up on the proof, so I guess it's not the end of it.

You can find an update here: http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/the-p%E2%89%A0np-proof-is-one-week-old/

Answer (score 21):

See the [wiki](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Deolalikar_P_vs_NP_paper).

Answer (score 6):

A nice article of RL Lipton can be found in [Communications of the ACM](http://cacm.acm.org/blogs/blog-cacm/97587-a-tale-of-a-serious-attempt-at-p≠np).