# At last P != NP or not

Tags: ds.algorithms, np, open-problem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the recent proof that P != NP correct?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-the-recent-proof-that-p-np-correct)

some weeks ago I heard a news that some one proof that P != NP ([link1](http://science.slashdot.org/story/10/08/08/226227/Claimed-Proof-That-P--NP) - [link2](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/a-proof-that-p-is-not-equal-to-np/)) andsome days later I heard that he was wrong (I can't find a link) can any one tell what was the truth?

Answer (score 4):

The question has already been covered here: [Is Deolalikar's 2010 proof that $P \ne NP$ correct?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-the-recent-proof-that-p-np-correct)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to follow Joel's link for a more detailed answer, but the current situation is that there have been a number of serious issues raised with the proof, and it is now deemed to be incorrect (and most likely irreparably so). There is currently a wiki keeping track of these issues [here](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Deolalikar%27s_P!%3DNP_paper), thanks largely to Suresh as well as Terrence Tao.